# Watch number of Threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I wrote a program with Python and it uses multi-threads, i want to know how many threads were executed with the timing and all of the statistics, is there a way to use the debugger to have those results ?

PS: i am using PyCharm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `threading` module rather than bare `thread`s, you can use [`threading.active_count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.active_count) as follows:

```py
num_threads = threading.active_count() # Python 3.x
num_threads = threading.activeCount() # Python 2.x
```

to get the amount of threads.  To get the threads themselves, use [`threading.enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.enumerate):

```
for th in threading.enumerate():
  # do whatever.
```

As far as timing and other statistics, you may have to track these manually, it looks like `Thread` objects are fairly scant of meta-data.

Comment: I used threading.activeCount() in fact to calculate the number of threads, but i had to modify the code to do so and it kinda ugly. Actually i found the process explorer of Windows really great for those kind of statistics without touching the code itself, but i wanted to know if there is another way, maybe special to python, and without touching to the code, for real time statistics.

Comment: Usually, the OS -level tool is better for this kind of thing, since the OS is what controls processes and threads.  If you need to make decisions based on this information within your code, you may be able to find what you need in the `os` module, which provides interfaces with whatever OS the program is running in.   https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html  Have fun dude